# How to get Mappable model class data in another ViewController in swift 3

Tags: swift3, objectmapper

I had a model Class of Mappable type in which i pass the data from api in firstViewController. Now i want to access the model class data in secondViewController. So how i can use the data in secondViewController.
Here is my code:

```
import ObjectMapper

class UserProfileResponse: Mappable {

var data:UserProfileData?
var success: Bool?
var error: String?

required init?(map: Map){

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    data <- map["data"]
    success <- map["success"]
    error <- map["error"]
}
}

class UserProfileData: Mappable {

var address: String?
var joinDate: String?
var phone: String?
var policyName: String?
var imageUrl: String?
var name: String?
var policyNo: String?
var title: String?

required init(map: Map){

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    address <- map["address"]
    joinDate <- map["joinDate"]
    phone <- map["phone"]
    policyName <- map["policyName"]
    imageUrl <- map["imageUrl"]
    name <- map["name"]
    policyNo <- map["policyNo"]
    title <- map["title"]
}

}
```

My FirstViewController from where i am sending the data to this model class

```
 func getUserProfileDataFromApi(){
    //Calling the method from Api class
    userProfileApi{completion in self.getProfileData(result: completion)}
}

func userProfileApi(completion:@escaping (_ result:UserProfileData)->()) {
let defaultObject = UserDefaults.standard
let headerToken = defaultObject.object(forKey: KHeaderToken) as! String
let headers = ["Authorization": headerToken]

Alamofire.request(KProfileUrl, method: .post, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
    .validate()
    .responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<UserProfileResponse>) in
        switch response.result{
        case .success:
            let value = response.result.value
            completion((value?.data)!)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
}
}
func getProfileData(result: UserProfileData){
   // Here i get all data in firstViewController
}

Now how i can get the UserProfileData in secondViewController.
```

Comment: @ASP Thanks that i konw but i am not navigating from first to second or vice versa. Actually secndVc view opens after choosing the option from menu. So it is not in navigation viewControllers stack. So what i need is that how i can create the object of UserProfileData and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Signleton class where you can populate your UserProfileData from the API response.

```
class UserProfileManager {
    static var userProfile: UserProfileData?

 private static var sharedManager: UserProfileManager = {
        let shared = UserProfileManager()
        return shared
    }()

    class func shared() -> UserProfileManager {
        return sharedManager
    }
}
```

you can access userProfileData from this singleton but this stays only during first time if you quit and launch it wont be there to do that store your info in UserDefaults.

Comment: Santosh one more thing how i can handle the null value in this class. I am getting null in response for "policyNo".

Comment: Mappable returns nil if it is nil. if you want to handle nil with some default value you can do this if let policyNum = map.JSON["policyNum"]{// assign value if not is nil}

Answer (score 0):

if you are showing the secondViewController from firstViewController using segue then you can use prepare segue to pass the data.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender _: Any?) {
            let destinationViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
 destinationViewController.userProfileData = self.userProfileData
}
```

Then your secondViewController will be like this with extra your implementation.

```
class SecondViewController{

var userProfileData:UserProfileData?
}
```

Comment: No bro, Actually i want to create the object of UserProfileData and then i want to use the values stored in that class which i got from API reposnse.
The solution you given is correct for passing the data b/w 2 controllers.